# Calculating the tangent at the point x = $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, tangent-line

I am finding the tangent at the point $\theta$ when $x = a\cos(\theta), y = b\sin(\theta)$

The tangent is calculated with the following
$$\frac{y-f(\theta)}{x-\theta}=f'(\theta)$$
at a point where $x=\theta$ and $y = f(\theta)$;

I have attempted the following:

$$\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})=\theta,  y = b\sin(\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))$$

Then this gives me the following:
$$\frac{y-b\sin(\cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}{x-a}=$$

However, this does not look like the correct approach to me.

I have instead attempted dividing $x$ over $y$ but cannot seem to find the solution. The expected solution is $x\cos(\theta/a)+y\sin(\theta/b)=1$.

Comment: I think you could use $\displaystyle \frac{y - y(\theta)}{x-x(\theta)} = \frac{y'(\theta)}{x'(\theta)}$

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you! thats definitely a working equation